# Excel VBA MouseDown MouseUp basics

Tags: excel, vba, shapes, mousedown, mouseup

I'm trying to use the MouseDown-Event in Microsoft Excel for a shape (a simple rectangle) and I have two major problems. The final goal is to run a macro when the shape is moved or changed in size.

Here is an example that I was trying to follow:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-mousedown-event-excel

Problem 1:
How can I figure out the "expression" name of my shape (corresponds to "Chart" in the example)? When adding the first shape into my worksheet, it is automatically called "Rectangle 1". However, this can't be the name I need to use in the code, because it has a space in it. There must be some other name by which to address it.

Problem 2: Nothing at all happens. I started with a completely blank workbook, added a rectangle, and inserted this code in the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Rectangle1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

MsgBox "HELLO!"

End Sub
```

(assuming I need to call the rectangle "Rectangle1"), but if I click on the shape, nothing happens.

---

**UPDATE**
I've come to the conclusion that Excel is not the right choice for the application I'm trying to build and will now start learning to code with JavaScript.

Comment: There is no MouseDown event for a shape. MouseDown event to a shape means you click the shape and hold down the left button. Why do you need that and why not just assign a macro to that shape so that when it is clicked it performs a specified action? Though there is a workaround i.e. after inserting a shape, insert an ActiveX Label Control over it and then open it's properties and set the BackStyle to Transparent and BorderStyle to None. Now double click the label, a Label Click event will be automatically inserted on the Sheet module.....

Comment: ....Now from the Procedure drop down, choose whatever event you like i.e. Mouse Down, Mouse Up or Mouse Over and perform some required stuff with it. After that, just come out of the design mode and your shape will respond according to the event you chose.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea! I'm trying to build an organization tool for my boss to help him assign workers to tasks and dates. It would be nice to use certain shapes as representations for the workers, and then simply drag and drop them around over schedule. However, I'm gonna use JavaScript now to implement such a tool.