# Continuous Press on Command Button

Tags: vba

[image]

If my mouse is pressed continuously on the Spin Button, the increment keeps happening. However, the Command Button requires me to click again and again. How can I have the Command Button behave in a similar fashion to that of a Spin Button?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Label1.Caption = Int(Label1.Caption) + 10
End Sub

Private Sub spbSpinButton_Change()
spbSpinButton.Min = 100
spbSpinButton.Max = 200
spbSpinButton.SmallChange = 10
Label1.Caption = spbSpinButton.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Why should you do that, please?

Comment: Aesthetics mainly, the objective is to have two separate buttons at either ends of the slide. The increasing and decreasing buttons shouldn't be connected.

Comment: But you must set an interval or a maximum to be reached. Without any delay the respective maximum will be reached almost instant. Why don't you place the label caption directly to that value? I can show you how a button click event can be called by itself, but it looks useless for me. Can you better explain what you mean by "Aesthetics" in this context? What do you really need accomplishing? Do you only want learning how such a behavior can be placed in a piece of code? Do you want the button incrementing during the period you click on it and keep the cursor down?

Comment: I had a quick look around because I was intrigued. potentially the answer to this question might help but I'm equally not sure and don't have time to chase down, hopefully it helps though [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770467/excel-vba-mousedown-mouseup-basics)

Comment: @FaneDuru, The upper bound can be set with `If Label1.Caption > 200 Then Label1.Caption = 200`. I need the button incrementing during the period I click on it and keep the cursor down. I understand that this is unconventional, the main objective is to not have the spin button joint, I need two separate buttons so that I can position it at either ends of the slide.

Comment: But you already received an answer (from @Sam) doing what you say... It is at least polite to check it and come back with feedback to the one posting the code. If it is something to be adapted you should tell what problem the code has against your need. If it works you should mark it as **accepted answer** and eventually vote it up, if he will consume his time for further adaptations...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the Click event, but if you keep track of MouseUp and MouseDown you can trigger a loop. Something like this:

### Add a module

Put this code in the module. Give the module any name, but it is referred to as Module1 below.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

### In your Form

Put this in your Module

```
Dim ButtonDown As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ButtonDown = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ButtonDown = True
    IncrementCounter
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ButtonDown = False
End Sub

Sub IncrementCounter()
    If ButtonDown Then
        Label1.Caption = Int(Label1.Caption) + 10
        DoEvents
        Module1.Sleep 100
        IncrementCounter
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Module1.Sleep 100` says wait 100 milliseconds. Adjust to your need.

Comment: Interesting solution. Is it possible to use `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` events for a command button in a worksheet (not a `UserForm`)?

Comment: `Sleep` is `(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` regardless of bitness.